# Getting Null pointer exception on insert : Sqllite & Android

Tags: android, sqlite, null, sql-insert

I am getting null pointer exception on the insert and I am not able to figure out the cause. Could you please help?
Code-

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "recorddb";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_0 = "MONTH";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_1 = "ERYTHROCYTE";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_2 = "HAEMOGLOBIN";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_3 = "PCV";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_4 = "RDW";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_5 = "MCV";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_6 = "MCH";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_7 = "MCHC";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_8 = "LEUCOCYTECOUNT";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_9 = "PLATELETS";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_10 = "NEUTROPHILS";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_11 = "EOSINOPHILS";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_12 = "LYMPHOCYTES";
    public static String CURRENT_MONTH = "CURRENT_MONTH";
    Cursor cursor = null;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "recorddb", null, 2);
    }

    /* Start of onCreate() */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
         db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recorddb (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, MONTH TEXT, ERYTHROCYTE TEXT, HAEMOGLOBIN TEXT, PCV TEXT, RDW TEXT, MCV TEXT, MCH TEXT, MCHC TEXT,LEUCOCYTECOUNT TEXT, PLATELETS TEXT, NEUTROPHILS  TEXT, EOSINOPHILS TEXT,LYMPHOCYTES TEXT);");
            //db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recorddb (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, MONTH TEXT, ERYTHROCYTE FLOAT, HAEMOGLOBIN FLOAT, PCV FLOAT, RDW FLOAT, MCV FLOAT, MCH FLOAT, MCHC FLOAT,LEUCOCYTECOUNT FLOAT, PLATELETS FLOAT, NEUTROPHILS FLOAT, EOSINOPHILS FLOAT,LYMPHOCYTES FLOAT);");
        } catch (SQLiteException sqlex) {
            Log.e("Logger:DBH:", "onCreate:SQLException::" + sqlex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Logger:DBH", "onCreate:SQL Exception:" + ex);
        } finally {
            db.close();     // Close Database Transaction
        }
        Log.e("Logger:DBH", "onCreate:Table created");
    }

    /* Start of onUpgrade() */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    /* Start of InsertRecord() */
    public boolean InsertRecord(String MONTH, Float ERYTHROCYTE, Float HAEMOGLOBIN, Float PCV, Float RDW, Float MCV, Float MCH, Float MCHC, Float LEUCOCYTECOUNT, Float PLATELETS, Float NEUTROPHILS, Float EOSINOPHILS, Float LYMPHOCYTES) {

        Log.e("Logger:DBH", "InsertRecord:Enter");
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();     // Get the Reference of the Database
        Log.e("Logger:DBH", "InsertRecord:ERYTHROCYTE" + ERYTHROCYTE);
        //duplicateMonthCheck
        if (duplicateMonthCheck(MONTH)) {
            Log.e("Logger:DBH", "InsertRecord:Duplicate Exists" + MONTH);
            //UtilityHelper.showMessage("Alert","Record for " + strDate + " already exists. Correct the month/year & try adding again", "Ok",new AddActivity());
            return false;
        } else {

            try {
                Log.e("Logger:DBH", "InsertRecord:Duplicate Not Exists" + MONTH);
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("MONTH", MONTH);
                values.put("ERYTHROCYTE", ERYTHROCYTE);
                values.put("HAEMOGLOBIN", HAEMOGLOBIN);
                values.put("PCV", PCV);
                values.put("RDW", RDW);
                values.put("MCV", MCV);
                values.put("MCH", MCH);
                values.put("MCHC", MCHC);
                values.put("LEUCOCYTECOUNT", LEUCOCYTECOUNT);
                values.put("PLATELETS", PLATELETS);
                values.put("NEUTROPHILS", NEUTROPHILS);
                values.put("EOSINOPHILS", EOSINOPHILS);
                values.put("LYMPHOCYTES", LYMPHOCYTES);

                Log.e("Logger:DBH", "InsertRecord Data >>" +MONTH+","+ ERYTHROCYTE+","+HAEMOGLOBIN+","+PCV+","+RDW+","+MCV+","+MCH+","+MCHC+","+LEUCOCYTECOUNT+","+PLATELETS+","+NEUTROPHILS+","+EOSINOPHILS+","+LYMPHOCYTES+" :");
                Log.e("Logger:DBH", "InsertRecord Month ..................");
                Log.e("Logger:DBH", "InsertRecord>>values.toString:: " + values.toString());
                Log.e("Logger:DBH", "InsertRecord Month .................."+db.getAttachedDbs());
                if (db.insert("recorddb", null, values) != -1)
                    return true;

            } catch (SQLiteException sqlex) {
                Log.e("Logger:DBH:", "InsertRecord:SQLException::" + sqlex+",ST :"+sqlex.getStackTrace());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("Logger:DBH", "InsertRecord: Exception:::" + ex +",toStr :"+ex);
                Log.e("Logger:DBH", "InsertRecord: Exception:::" + ex +",LocMsg :"+ex.initCause(null));
                Log.e("Logger:DBH", "InsertRecord: Exception:::" + ex +",ST :"+ex.getStackTrace());
            } finally {
                db.close();     // Close Database Transaction
            }
            Log.e("Logger:DBH", "InsertRecord:Exit");
            return false;
        }
    }

    /* End of InsertRecord() */

    /* Start of duplicateMonthCheck()*/
    public boolean duplicateMonthCheck(String month) {

        Log.e("Logger:DBH", "duplicateMonthCheck:Enter");
        ArrayList recByMonth = new ArrayList<>();
        recByMonth = getRecordsByMonth(month);
        if (recByMonth != null && !recByMonth.isEmpty()) {
            Log.e("Logger:DBH", "duplicateMonthCheck:Yes duplicates");
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.e("Logger:DBH", "duplicateMonthCheck: No duplicates");
            return false;
        }

    }
    /* End of duplicateMonthCheck()*/
```

---- Remaining functions of the class removed-----------

Log :

```
06-22 11:34:19.760 30764-30764/com.ajay.projects.activity E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method com.ajay.projects.models.UtilityHelper.access$super
 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method com.ajay.projects.models.UtilityHelper.access$super
 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method com.ajay.projects.models.UtilityHelper.access$super
 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method com.ajay.projects.models.UtilityHelper.access$super
 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.ajay.projects.models.UtilityHelper.access$super
 E/Logger:Utility: getCurrentMonthList() Enter
 E/Logger:Utility: getCurrentMonthList() Exit[Ljava.lang.String;@412be7f8
 E/Logger:Utility: getCurrentYear() Enter
 E/Logger:Utility: getCurrentYear() Exit[Ljava.lang.String;@412bf200
 E/Logger:AddActivity:: OnCreate:Enter
 E/Logger:DBH: getMonthList:Enter
 E/Logger:DBH: SELECT MONTH FROM recorddb1
 E/Logger:DBH: SELECT MONTH FROM recorddb : xNewData to Array[Ljava.lang.Object;@412e9510
 E/Logger:DBH: SELECT MONTH FROM recorddb : xNewData to Array[Ljava.lang.Object;@412e9818
 E/Logger:DBH: getMonthList:Exit
 E/Logger:Base: dataExists True
 E/Logger:AddActivity:: OnCreate:nef GetINflator
 E/Logger:AddActivity:: OnCreate:Enter2
 E/Logger:AddActivity:: OnCreate:Enter3
 E/Logger:AddActivity: setMonthSpinner:Enter
 E/Logger:AddActivity: setMonthSpinner:Exit
 E/Logger:AddActivity: setYearSpinner:Enter
 E/Logger:AddActivity: setYearSpinner:Exit
 E/Logger:AddActivity:: OnCreate:After Spinner1
 E/Logger:AddActivity:: OnCreate:Exit
  E/Logger:AddActivity: onClick:isNotEmpty
  E/Logger:AddActivity: btnAdd:OnClick-SelectedMonth>>Feb-2016
  E/Logger:AddActivity: btnAdd:getText().toString:Feb-2016','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','22','2','2','2
  E/Logger:AddActivity: btnAdd:getText():Feb-2016','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','22','2','2','2
  E/Logger:DBH: InsertRecord:Enter
  E/Logger:DBH: InsertRecord:ERYTHROCYTE2.0
  E/Logger:DBH: duplicateMonthCheck:Enter
  E/Logger:DBH:: getRecordsByMonth:EnterFeb-2016
  E/Logger:DBH:: getRecordsByMonth:Exit
  E/Logger:DBH: duplicateMonthCheck: No duplicates
  E/Logger:DBH: InsertRecord:Duplicate Not ExistsFeb-2016
  E/Logger:DBH: InsertRecord Data >>Feb-2016,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,0.002,0.22,2.0,2.0,2.0 :
  E/Logger:DBH: InsertRecord Month ..................
  E/Logger:DBH: InsertRecord>>values.toString:: LYMPHOCYTES=2.0 NEUTROPHILS=2.0 LEUCOCYTECOUNT=0.002 MCH=2.0 PCV=2.0 PLATELETS=0.22 HAEMOGLOBIN=2.0 MCHC=2.0 MCV=2.0 RDW=2.0 MONTH=Feb-2016 EOSINOPHILS=2.0 ERYTHROCYTE=2.0
  E/Logger:DBH: InsertRecord Month ..................null
  E/Logger:DBH: InsertRecord: Exception:::java.lang.NullPointerException,toStr :java.lang.NullPointerException
  E/Logger:DBH: InsertRecord: Exception:::java.lang.NullPointerException,LocMsg :java.lang.NullPointerException
  E/Logger:DBH: InsertRecord: Exception:::java.lang.NullPointerException,ST :[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@4139d8e8
  E/Logger:DBH: InsertRecord:Exit
  E/Logger:Util: ShowMessage : Enter
  E/Logger:Util: ShowMessage : Details-AlertRecord for Feb-2016 already exists. Correct the month/year & try adding againOkcom.ajay.projects.activity.AddActivity@412b3668
  E/Logger:Util: ShowMessage : Exit
```

--------------------- End of Log-----------------

Comment: Can you code where you are inserting data to database?

Comment: In the above code, I am inserting data at "if (db.insert("recorddb", null, values) != -1)". Was that your question? Even the stacktrace is not giving detail of why I am getting the null pointer. I have printed Exception and stacktrace in the log that I have shared here.

Comment: Are you initializing your `db` before calling insert funstion?

Comment: There is no stack trace in your log. Remove all those `catch`es and let the system print the stack trace.

Comment: Yes. SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

Comment: put a printStackTrace() in your catch block and share log

Comment: Log of catch block is shared. The last 5 lines starting with 'Exception:::' are output of catch block.Thanks

Comment: Error Resolved: The error got resolved when I commented db.close();  in my finally block. I realized this because because before I added 'db.close(); ' the code was working fine.  I was under the impression that closing the database is good housekeeping but it seems you do not have to close DB everytime you make a call to SQLiteDatabase . Could you look at my code and tell me why db.close() would give a null pointer exception?                                                                   Thanks for your time & I appreciate your help